# Code will not use first line of table in ws

Tags: excel, vba

Ok. I recently created a Userform that allows someone to input information that is then inserted into a table on a worksheet. My issue is that the code for inserting the data doesn't insert information into the blank first line of the table (assuming a completely empty table with headers)
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub EnterCommand_Click()
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Check for next empty row
NextRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'Add the data
ws.Cells(NextRow, 1).Value = WeekTextBox.Value
ws.Cells(NextRow, 2).Value = DOSTextBox.Value
ws.Cells(NextRow, 3).Value = InvTextBox.Value
ws.Cells(NextRow, 4).Value = TechComboBox.Value
ws.Cells(NextRow, 5).Value = HospComboBox.Value
ws.Cells(NextRow, 6).Value = HoursTextBox.Value

'Close
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Not sure what to do to force it to use the initial blank line of the table on the sheet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

of course there is always

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select 
   If ActiveCell.Row = 1 Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
   Else
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   End If
```

Comment: You need to change the row number in "If ActiveCell.Row = 1 Then" from "1" to what ever the row number is for the first row in the tabl.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to actively search for the next empty row? Why not use a variable to track the current row?

```
dim NextRow As Long
NextRow= 1

Private Sub EnterCommand_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")'Add the data

    ws.Cells(NextRow, 1).Value = WeekTextBox.Value
    ws.Cells(NextRow, 2).Value = DOSTextBox.Value
    ws.Cells(NextRow, 3).Value = InvTextBox.Value
    ws.Cells(NextRow, 4).Value = TechComboBox.Value
    ws.Cells(NextRow, 5).Value = HospComboBox.Value
    ws.Cells(NextRow, 6).Value = HoursTextBox.Value

    NextRow = NextRow + 1
End Sub
'Close
```

Comment: Not sure why, but tested it and it doesn't recognize the NextRow = NextRow + 1. I honestly think it's my works computers. I have written code at home that did not move over to one or more of the work computers exactly the same. Had to change the code when I got to work. UG

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the last row:

```
NextRow = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(what:="*", after:=ws.Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1,0).Row
```

You're having problems because you're dealing with <kbd>Tables</kbd>.
Your code will work if your data is in the form of <kbd>Ranges</kbd>.

Here's the logic:

```
ws.Range("A1",ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) '~~> This identifies the search range
```

If your table is empty above will evaluate to:

```
Ws.Range("A1","A2") '~~> A2 because that is where the table ends, if this is Range it is A1
```

Above is equivalent to this:

```
ws.Range("A1:A2")
```

Then you use `.Find` function to find the last data with entry.

```
ws.Range("A1:A2").Find(what:="*",after:ws.Range("A1"),searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
```

`Find` has many arguments but in your case we only need 3 specified above.
What it does is that it finds the last previous cell with data referenced at `A1`.
Hope this helps.